# PyQT4 and QPixmap: load image with size zero?

Tags: python, image, pyqt4, qpixmap

I am confused by PyQt4. I have tried the following steps on python2.6:

```
In [1]: from PyQt4 import QtGui

In [2]: import sys

In [3]: app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

In [4]: pix = QtGui.QPixmap("P1010001.JPG")

In [5]: pix.width(), pix.height()
Out[5]: (0, 0)
```

Why does `width` and `height` show zero? The image exists and is fine. This is completely counterintuitive, which I do not expect from python.

Comment: Can you show us the image that's causing you this problem?

Answer (score 3):

PyQt adds a little syntactic sugar here and there to make things more Pythonic. But it is mostly a fairly thin wrapper around Qt (which is a C++ library) - and so it would be a mistake to expect PyQt to *always* behave in a way that is intuitive to Python programmers.

I suppose most Python programmers might expect QPixmap to raise an error when setting a path that doesn't exist. But Qt doesn't do this, and, in this case, neither does PyQt. Instead, you can check that you have a valid pixmap by using:

```
pix.isNull()
```

To actually fix the code in your example, you will obviously have to change to the appropriate directory first (or use an absolute path).

Comment: The path in the example is absolutely correct. That's the whole point of the question. I have extracted those lines from a piece of code which actually shows the image on screen.

Comment: @Alex. That wasn't clear from your question, so I went for the simplest explanation. All I can say is it works fine for me using various jpg, gif, png, and tif images. So: does this problem happen with all images, or just this one particular image?