# Python: PyQt QPixmap returns Null for a valid image

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

I'm trying to load [this .tiff image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pte2sekc7zwaoja/PR8_GT1.tiff) into my gui interface using PyQt's `QPixmap`. I have the following code:

```
fileName = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self.parent, "Open Image", "/", "Image Files (*.png *.jpg *.bmp *.tiff)");
img = QtGui.QPixmap(fileName)
scaled_img = img.scaled(self.ui.img_label.size(), QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
self.ui.img_label.setPixmap(scaled_img)
```

Where `img_label` is a `Qlabel` in my GUI. I tested it with various `.jpg`, `.png` and `.tiff` images. It seems to be working, but when I test it on [this image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pte2sekc7zwaoja/PR8_GT1.tiff), it returns `Null`

### What I have tried

- I have tried printing `QImageReader.supportedImageFormats` and it shows that `.tiff` is supported
- Also tried [checking the MIME type of the image](http://mime.ritey.com/) and it shows as `image/tiff`

Can someone suggest what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Note that "TIFF" is a complicated and very flexible file container format, so most libraries that can "handle TIFF" can't actually handle all legal TIFF files. For example, some libraries can't do FAX compression, or CMYK color, or 24bpp RGB, or tiled files, or…

Comment: After downloading and checking out this file, it seems to be about as common as can be—a single image with LZW (#5) compression, 96dpi, RGB at 8bpp, no color profile, little-endian 32-bit offsets, … So I'm not so sure the usual "Thousands of Incompatible File Formats" issue is to blame here.

Comment: @abarnert It's weird because [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13848442/pyqt4-and-qpixmap-load-image-with-size-zero) seems to have the similar problem with a .jpg image ..

Comment: When I try this with Qt 4.8.4 and 5.0.1 (from Homebrew, on 64-bit Mac OS X 10.8), they both have no problem displaying the image, or scaling it to any size I want, so… What platform, and what version of Qt, are you using?

Comment: I'm on 32-bit Windows, using [winpython](http://code.google.com/p/winpython/) for python 2.7

Comment: This could well be a bug in the C++ code. If you're not using the latest revision for your major version (I think 4.8.4 and 5.0.2, as of today, but check with the website), you may want to try upgrading before going too far with the debugging. And then look at the bug database to see if this has already been reported. And, if you have the commercial rather than LGPL license, or have bought support separately, open a dev support ticket.

Comment: Which version of winpython? Or, more importantly, which versions of Qt4 and PyQt4 does it include?

Comment: @abarnert I tried installing Qt 4.8.4 on a fresh Python 2.7.3 installation, but it still gives me the same error. Also searched through the mailing list and couldn't find something similar. I'll try sending an email to their mailing list.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, this is a bit strange. The image loads when I change the line:

```
img = QtGui.QPixmap(fileName)
```

To:

```
img = QtGui.QPixmap(fileName, "1")
```

In fact it seems to work when I specify any numeric string for the second argument. I'm not sure the second argument is supposed to be as [the documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qpixmap.html#QPixmap-4) is a bit vague about it. I hope someone can explain what's happening, as this is really puzzling me.

Comment: The second argument should be a valid image format from one of the values listed at - 
http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qpixmap.html#reading-and-writing-image-files

Answer (score 1):

QFileDialog.getOpenFileName() returns a tuple.
try this instead:

```
fileName = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self.parent, "Open Image", "/", "Image Files (*.png *.jpg *.bmp *.tiff)");
img = QtGui.QPixmap(fileName[0])
scaled_img = img.scaled(self.ui.img_label.size(), QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
self.ui.img_label.setPixmap(scaled_img)
```

Comment: It returns a tuple for PySide, but returns a string for PyQt. That was not my problem, sorry.